# how to receive SOAP envelope thru REST?

Tags: java, rest, soap, jaxb

I have a system that returns SOAP envelope message

```
<soap:Envelope>
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:myResponse>
```

And i have classes generated from WADL and XSD files (by cxf-wadl2java-plugin and JAXB), also i have an interface generated (imports from javax.ws.rs ):

```
@Path("/case/{id}")
public interface MyService {

    @GET
    @Produces("application/xml")
    Response getCase(@PathParam("id") String id);
```

How should the client looks like ?
I've tried with Jersey:

```
  com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client client = Client.create();
  WebResource resource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/case");
```

and CXF:

MyService service = JAXRSClientFactory.create("http://localhost:8080", MyService.class, providers);

but during a call i have (i'm not surprised) a problem with unmarshalling:

```
unexpected element (uri:"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope", local:"Envelope"). Expected elements are <{}myResponse>
```

how to create working client for this?

it was a WS before (with WSDL, binding file and XSDs with cxf-codegen-plugin plugin)

Comment: REST can't operate with SOAP as SOAP isn't data format but protocol. I think you want to transfer just xml via REST, right? Then you don't need soap: elements in xml at least.

Comment: as i tried to explain, maybe strange mix, but that's what it is. my object is returned in <soap:Envelope> <soap:Body> ....   tags.
 and the request is just REST, without SOAP

Comment: Ok, but why do you use REST instead of SOAP? But if you need exactly REST you should consider your xml not as object's xml representation but as just xml and do some transformations and marshalling  by yourself. Actually this is just my theory. I didn't have practice with SOAP body over REST as the absolute majority of developers. If you find solution let us know, please - it's really interesting.

Comment: i'm looking for elegant solution, so classes and everything generated from WADL,WSDL,XSD files. i don't know even if it's a 'legitimate' solution, but i don't have a choice (<soap:envelope> from REST service)